# Наследование классов с использованием разных типов данных

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Задание: из двух разных объектов сделать один. Один из объектов - класс Аккаунт, методы: сложение, вычитание, начисление процентов, преобразование в евро, доллар и написание числа прописью. Второй - Деньги, представленный рублями, и копейками. Нужно сумму из Аккаунта, заменить деньгами из класса Деньги. Последнее, что нужно сделать: написать сумму прописью. Я не могу сделать так, чтобы сумма после начисления процентов записалась в новую переменную класса. И не могу сделать так, чтобы в прописи было написано рубли и копейки. Подскажите как исправить?
Это H файлы двух классов

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Money.h"


using namespace std;

class Account
{
private:
    std::string family;
    int number;
    float percent;
    Money summa;
public:
    Account();
    Account(std::string, int, float, Money);
    Account(const Account&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Account&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Account&);
    void setFamily(std::string new_family);
    void getMoney(Money&g);
    void putMoney(Money&p);
    void percentCalculate(Money&perc);
    Money changeToEuro();
    Money changeToDollar();
    std::string toString(Money&st) const;
};
#endif // ACCOUNT

#ifndef MONEY
#define MONEY
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Money
{
private:
    long ruble;
    unsigned char kopeck;

public:
    unsigned sum_in_cop() const
    {
        return (int)kopeck + ruble * 100;
    };
    Money();
    Money(long, unsigned char);
    Money(const Money&);

    long get_ruble() {return ruble;};
    unsigned char get_kopeck() {return kopeck;};

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Money&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Money&);
    string toString() const;

    const Money back_transfer(long);
    const Money transfer(long);

    friend const Money operator+(const Money&, const Money&);
    friend const Money operator-(const Money&, const Money&);
    friend const Money operator/(const Money&, double);
    friend const Money operator*(const Money&, double);
    friend double operator/(const Money&, const Money&);
    bool operator==(const Money&);
    bool operator<(const Money&);
    bool operator>(const Money&);
};
#endif // MONEY
```

Это CPP файлы классов

```
#include "Account.h"
#include "Money.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

Account::Account(): family (), number (), percent (), summa () {};
Account::Account(std::string theFamily, int theNumber, float thePercent, Money theSumma):
    family(theFamily), number(theNumber), percent(thePercent), summa(theSumma) {};

Account::Account(const Account&other)
{
    family = other.family;
    number = other.number;
    percent = other.percent;
    summa = other.summa;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream&out, const Account&a)
{
    out << a.family << ", " << a.number << ", " << a.percent << ", " << a.summa;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream&in, Account&a)
{
    in >> a.family >> a.number >> a.percent >> a.summa;
    return in;
}

void Account::setFamily(std::string new_family)
{
    family = new_family;
}
void Account::getMoney(Money&g)
{
    if (summa < g)
        cout << "Вы не можете снять больше, чем есть на счету" << endl;
    else{
        summa = summa - g;
        cout << "Сумма после снятия: " << summa;
    }
}
void Account::putMoney(Money&p)
{
    summa = summa + p;
    cout << "Сумма после зачисления: " << summa;
}
void Account::percentCalculate(Money&perc)
{
    summa = summa + ((summa * (double) percent) / 100);
    cout << "Сумма после начисления процентов: " << summa;
}
Money Account::changeToEuro()
{
    summa = summa / 70.0;
    return summa;
}
Money Account::changeToDollar()
{
    summa = summa / 60.0;
    return summa;
}

char* toString(int num, char *s, char* t)
{
  int position = 0;
  int x[4];
  int div = 1000;
  int var = num;
  int rest;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    rest = (int)(var / div);
    x[i] = rest;
    var = var - rest*div;
    div = div / 10;
  }

  switch (x[0])
  {
    case 1: strcpy(s, "Одна тысяча "); break;
    case 2: strcpy(s, "Две тысячи "); break;
    case 3: strcpy(s, "Три тысячи "); break;
    case 4: strcpy(s, "Четыре тысячи "); break;
    case 5: strcpy(s, "Пять тысяч "); break;
    case 6: strcpy(s, "Шесть тысяч "); break;
    case 7: strcpy(s, "Семь тысяч "); break;
    case 8: strcpy(s, "Восемь тысяч "); break;
    case 9: strcpy(s, "Девять тысяч "); break;
    default: break;
  }
  position = strlen(s);

  switch (x[1])
  {
    case 1: strcpy(s + position, "сто "); break;
    case 2: strcpy(s + position, "двести "); break;
    case 3: strcpy(s + position, "триста "); break;
    case 4: strcpy(s + position, "четыреста "); break;
    case 5: strcpy(s + position, "пятьсот "); break;
    case 6: strcpy(s + position, "шестьсот "); break;
    case 7: strcpy(s + position, "семьсот "); break;
    case 8: strcpy(s + position, "восемьсот "); break;
    case 9: strcpy(s + position, "девятьсот "); break;
    default: break;
  }
  position = strlen(s);

  switch (x[2])
  {
    case 1:

    switch (x[3])
    {
      case 0: strcpy(s + position, "десять "); break;
      case 1: strcpy(s + position, "одиннадцать "); break;
      case 2: strcpy(s + position, "двенадцать "); break;
      case 3: strcpy(s + position, "тринадцать "); break;
      case 4: strcpy(s + position, "четырнадцать "); break;
      case 5: strcpy(s + position, "пятнадцать "); break;
      case 6: strcpy(s + position, "шестнадцать "); break;
      case 7: strcpy(s + position, "семнадцать "); break;
      case 8: strcpy(s + position, "восемнадцать "); break;
      case 9: strcpy(s + position, "девятнадцать "); break;
    }
    x[3] = 0;
    position = strlen(s);
    break;
    case 2: strcpy(s + position, "двадцать "); break;
    case 3: strcpy(s + position, "тридцать "); break;
    case 4: strcpy(s + position, "сорок "); break;
    case 5: strcpy(s + position, "пятьдесят "); break;
    case 6: strcpy(s + position, "шестьдесят "); break;
    case 7: strcpy(s + position, "семьдесят "); break;
    case 8: strcpy(s + position, "восемьдесят "); break;
    case 9: strcpy(s + position, "девяносто "); break;
    default: break;
  }
  position = strlen(s);

  switch (x[3]) {
    case 1: strcpy(s + position, "один "); break;
    case 2: strcpy(s + position, "два "); break;
    case 3: strcpy(s + position, "три "); break;
    case 4: strcpy(s + position, "четыре "); break;
    case 5: strcpy(s + position, "пять "); break;
    case 6: strcpy(s + position, "шесть "); break;
    case 7: strcpy(s + position, "семь "); break;
    case 8: strcpy(s + position, "восемь "); break;
    case 9: strcpy(s + position, "девять "); break;
    default: break;
  }
  position = strlen(s);
  return s;
}

std::string Account::toString (Money&st) const
{
string str;
char s[100];
int choice = st.get_kopeck();
int choice2 = st.get_ruble();
str = ::toString(choice2, s, " rubles ");
str = ::toString(choice, s, " copecks ");
return str;
}



#include "money.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Money::Money(): ruble(0), kopeck(0) {};
Money::Money(long ruble_, unsigned char kopeck_): ruble(ruble_), kopeck(kopeck_) {};
Money::Money(const Money& other): ruble(other.ruble), kopeck(other.kopeck) {};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Money& m)
{
    out << m.ruble << "." << (int)m.kopeck << endl;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Money& m)
{
    in >> m.ruble >> m.kopeck;
    return in;
}

const Money back_transfer(long a){
    long ruble_;
    unsigned char kopeck_;
    ruble_ = a/100;
    kopeck_ = a%100;
    return Money(ruble_, kopeck_);
}

const Money transfer(long b){
    long ruble_;
    unsigned char summa_kopeck, kopeck_;
    ruble_ = b*100;
    summa_kopeck = ruble_ + kopeck_;
    return Money(ruble_, summa_kopeck);
}

const Money operator+(const Money&arg1, const Money&arg2){
    unsigned sum_in_cop;
    long summa_ruble;
    unsigned char summa_kopeck;
    sum_in_cop = arg1.sum_in_cop() + arg2.sum_in_cop();
    summa_ruble = sum_in_cop / 100;
    summa_kopeck = sum_in_cop % 100;
    return Money(summa_ruble, summa_kopeck);
}

const Money operator-(const Money& arg1, const Money& arg2){
    unsigned sum_in_cop;
    long summa_ruble;
    unsigned char summa_kopeck;
    sum_in_cop = arg1.sum_in_cop() - arg2.sum_in_cop();
    summa_ruble = sum_in_cop / 100;
    summa_kopeck = sum_in_cop %100;
    return Money(summa_ruble, summa_kopeck);
}

double operator/(const Money &arg1, const Money &arg2){
    double division_result;
    division_result = (double)arg1.sum_in_cop() / (double)arg2.sum_in_cop();
    return division_result;
}

const Money operator/(const Money &arg1, double arg2){
    Money division_result;
    unsigned long quotient;

    quotient = arg1.sum_in_cop() / (arg2);
    division_result = back_transfer(quotient);

    return division_result;
}

const Money operator*(const Money &arg1, double arg2){
    Money multi_result;
    unsigned long composition;

    composition = ((double)arg1.sum_in_cop() * (arg2));
    multi_result = back_transfer(composition);

    return multi_result;
}

bool Money :: operator<(const Money&p){
    return (sum_in_cop() < p.sum_in_cop());
}
```

И Main файл

```
#include "Account.h"
#include "Money.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale (0, "");
    Account a1 ("Volzhin", 35, 10.5, Money (30, 10));
    Money m1 (50, 50);
    Money m2 (20, 10);

    cout << a1;

    a1.getMoney(m2);
    a1.putMoney(m1);
    a1.percentCalculate(m1);

    Money m3 ();

    Account a2 (a1);
    Account a3 (a1);
    a1.changeToDollar();
    a2.changeToEuro();
    cout << "Счет с суммой в долларах: " << a1 << "Счет с суммой в евро: " << a2 << endl;
    cout << a3.toString(m2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: что по вашему означает:  из двух разных объектов сделать один?

Comment: Первоначально было две разных задачи, одна: создать класс аккаунт и методы: снятие суммы, зачисление суммы, начисление процентов, перевод в евро, доллары и сумму прописью написать. Вторая: класс мани, где будут рубли и копейки, а в этой задаче нужно сумму из класса Аккаунт заменить рублями и копейками из класса Мани.

Comment: и по вашему это и есть: из двух разных объектов сделать один? Отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение отвечаючих.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что не нужно нагружать класс разными бесполезными вещами. Абстракцию нужно создавать исходя из поставленных целей для класса (Страуструп читайте побольше). Например ваш класс денег может содержать не два целочисленных типа, а один с плавающей точкой. Тогда все математические операции сделаются естественным путем:

```
class Money {
    double  sum;
public:
    Money(const double money) : sum(money) {}
    Money(const int rub,  int p)
    {            
        while(int(p)) p /= 10;
        sum = rub + p;
    }

    int get_ruble() const {return int(sum); }
    int get_kopeck() const
    {
        double d = sum - int(sum);
        //поскольку нам нужны два знака для коппек
        d *= 100;
        return round(d);  
        // функция(из <math.h>) выдаст округленное значение 
    }
    operator double() { return sum; }
};
```

Думаю для этого класса больше ничего не нужно. Хотя всегда можно найти иное решение....

Дальше у вас класс какого то аккаунта. Назовите как хотите, я назову его вкладчиком.
Вкладчик имеет деньги, означает, что мы должны содержать в классе обьект_деньги. В данном случаи наследование и ассоциация неуместны:

```
class Depositor {
public:
    Depositor(const string& name, Money deposit = 0)
        : full_name(name), m(deposit) {}

    void set_name(const std::string& new_name) { full_name = new_name; }
    // положим деньги на счет
    void putMoney(Money& rise) { m = double(m) + double(rise); }
    // добавим по проценту
    void percentCalculate(double perc) { double t = perc * m / 100; m = double(m) + t; }
    //на что вы поменяете, указывать должна вызывающая функция(к примеру программа)
    Money change(double ratio)  { return Money(double(m) * ratio) ; }
    double getMoney() { return m; }
   // строковое представление имеющихся денег
    const std::string get_string_rep()
    {
        int r = m.get_ruble(),
             c = m.get_kopeck();
        std::string str;
        add_string(str, r);
        str += " руб. ";
        add_string(str, c);
        str += " коп.";
        return str;
    }
private:
    std::string full_name;
    Money m;
    //статический член, поскольку для всех обьектов таблица строкового представления
    //чисел одинакова
    static std::map<int, std::string> table;
    void  add_string(std::string& s, const int k)
    {
        if (table[k] == "") {
            /*если  не определена в таблице такая строка
            то смотрим в каком диапазоне число, и
            и определяем эту строку на основе имеющихся. Например:
            table[3300] = table[3] + ' ' + table[1000] + ' ' + table[3] + table[100];*/
        }
        s += table[k];
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Depositor&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Depositor&);
};
std::map<int, std::string> Depositor::table
= {{0, "ноль"}, {1, "один"}, {2,"два"}, {3, "три"}, {4, "четыре"}, {5, "пять"},
   {6, "шесть"}, {7, "семь"}, {8, "восемь"}, {9, "девять"}, {10, "десять"},
   {20, "двадцать"}, /*...*/ {100, "сто"}, {200, "двести"}, {1000, "тысяча"}  };
//остальные строки могут сложиться из этих с добавлением. Если нет, то добавьте в таблицу
```

Вы можете определить таблицу чисел и строк по другому, если не знакомы с `std::map`, например `массивом пар`, но суть не изменится.  Можете и класс написать по другому, но не очень хорошо понимая ваш вопрос(формулировка сама непонятна), я просто написал образец класса, обьекты которого могут выполнить в программе поставленные задачи.

И можете написать программу:

```
Depositor d("Grigoryi", Money(1000));
cout << d.get_string_rep(); // вывод:  "тысяча руб. ноль коп."
```

Comment: P.S. Я написал быстро, поэтому могут быть ошибки и недоработки.  Улучшение оставлю за вас